# Variable declared in one script is undefined in another

Tags: javascript

In my html I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/photos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mattes.js"></script>
```

In common.js I have:

```
var mattes_openings_xml;
```

In mattes.js I have:

```
mattes_openings_xml = "<Openings><opening><item><x>7.75</x><y>1.75</y><width>4.5</width><height>6.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening><opening><item><x>14</x><y>2.25</y><width>3.5</width><height>5.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening><opening><item><x>2.5</x><y>2.25</y><width>3.5</width><height>5.5</height><type>rectangle</type><clipX>0</clipX><clipY>0</clipY><imgsrc></imgsrc></item></opening></Openings>";
```

In photos.js I have:

```
console.log(mattes_openings_xml);
```

which outputs as undefined.

I do not understand why this is happening because the function (in mattes.js) that defines mattes_openings_xml is called before the function that outputs it (photos.js).

Answer (score 0):

You're loading photos.js before mattes.js, so photos.js happens first. It's only after photos.js runs that you define mattes_openings_xml.

Comment: How can I get around this? I have to load photos.js before mattes.js

Comment: Well, photos.js has a dependancy on that mattes_openings_xml, so logically that should be defined first. I don't know exactly how the application is structured, but consider defining it sooner, either in photos.js or in another js file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by calling:

```
function mattes_get_xml()
{
  return mattes_openings_xml;
}
```